# How to derive new columns in YYYYMM format between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I have following table

| ID | Name | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aa | 2021-10-14 | 2021-12-22 |
| 2 | Ab | 2021-12-02 | 2022-10-05 |

The requirement is to add new columns in YYYYMM format consisting of all the months between min(StartDate) and max(EndDate), and assign values to the corresponding cells. The cell value should be 1 if the date lies between StartDate and EndDate in that row, and should be 0 if it does not fall within that date range.The final output should be like in the below table

| ID | Name | StartDate | EndDate | 202110 | 202111 | 202112 | 202201 | 202202 | 202203 | 202204 | 202205 | 202206 | 202207 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aa | 2021-10-14 | 2021-12-22 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Ab | 2021-12-02 | 2022-07-05 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

For the 1st row, since the startdate=2021-10-14 & EndDate=2021-12-22, corresponding new columns should be 202110,202111 & 202112; and corresponding cell values are 1 for these columns while the other cells are 0. Same logic should be applied to other rows as well.

I could not figure out the logic to derive new tables with new columns and corresponding cell values.

Comment: This "requirement" smells like a design nightmare. Don't, just *don't*... Use a **normalised** signed.

Comment: it smells like it because it is. This just isn't sustainable at all

Comment: If you *really* need a column per value, then this is really a job for the presentation layer to pivot the data.

Comment: You are likely going to need a dynamic SQL to generate what may be a variable number of columns. First you need to determine the range. Next generate the needed year-month values, and then dynamically generate select items of the form `CASE WHEN (start/end overlaps month) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [yyyymm]`.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to rethink your design / approach. How many columns do you think you would want if you had two rows with a start date in 2001 and a start date in 2023. You'll need *hundreds* of columns to accomodate the potential varietly of dates over N rows. Clearly this is just silly and should not be done in Sql Server.

Comment: @Stu It will be for about 3- 4 years. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Usially the way to do this is using Dynamic SQL to first determin the columns and build the corresponding SQL, possibly a sneaky way may exist via json.

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach using dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Data ( ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100), StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE )
INSERT Data
VALUES
    ('1', 'Aa', '2021-10-14', '2021-12-22'),
    ('2', 'Ab', '2021-12-02', '2022-10-05')

-- Extract overall date range
DECLARE @MinStartDate DATE, @MaxEndDate AS DATE
SELECT @MinStartDate = MIN(StartDate), @MaxEndDate =  MAX(EndDate)
FROM Data

-- Convert to months (DATETRUNC() may be used instead with SQL Server 2022 and later)
DECLARE @StartMonth DATE = DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(@MinStartDate), @MinStartDate)
DECLARE @EndMonth DATE = DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(@MaxEndDate), @MaxEndDate)

-- Generate calendar of months within range
DECLARE @Months TABLE ( Month DATE)
;WITH Months AS (
   SELECT @StartMonth AS Month
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, M.Month)
   FROM Months M
   WHERE M.Month < @EndMonth
)
INSERT @Months
SELECT M.Month
FROM Months M

-- Define SQL Templates
DECLARE @SqlTemplate VARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT ID, Name, StartDate, EndDate
<ColumnSql>
FROM Data D
ORDER BY D.Name
'

DECLARE @ColumnTemplate VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= <MonthEnd> AND <MonthStart> <= D.EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS <ColumnName>'

-- Build month-specific column select items from template
DECLARE @ColumnSql VARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(C.ColumnSql, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY M.Month)
    FROM @Months M
    CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT
            CONVERT(CHAR(6), M.Month, 112) AS ColumnName,
            M.Month AS MonthStart,
            EOMONTH(M.Month) AS MonthEnd
    ) MD
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            @ColumnTemplate
            , '<ColumnName>', QUOTENAME(MD.ColumnName))
            , '<MonthStart>', QUOTENAME(CONVERT(CHAR(8), MD.MonthStart, 112), ''''))
            , '<MonthEnd>', QUOTENAME(CONVERT(CHAR(8), MD.MonthEnd, 112), ''''))
            AS ColumnSql
    ) C
)

--SELECT @ColumnSql

-- Build final SQL
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE(@SqlTemplate, '<ColumnSql>', @ColumnSql)

SELECT @Sql

-- Deliver
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT ID, Name, StartDate, EndDate

    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20211031' AND D.EndDate >= '20211001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202110]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20211130' AND D.EndDate >= '20211101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202111]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20211231' AND D.EndDate >= '20211201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202112]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220131' AND D.EndDate >= '20220101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202201]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220228' AND D.EndDate >= '20220201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202202]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220331' AND D.EndDate >= '20220301' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202203]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220430' AND D.EndDate >= '20220401' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202204]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220531' AND D.EndDate >= '20220501' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202205]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220630' AND D.EndDate >= '20220601' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202206]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220731' AND D.EndDate >= '20220701' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202207]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220831' AND D.EndDate >= '20220801' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202208]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20220930' AND D.EndDate >= '20220901' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202209]
    , CASE WHEN D.StartDate <= '20221031' AND D.EndDate >= '20221001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [202210]
FROM Data D
ORDER BY D.Name
```

Results:

| ID | Name | StartDate | EndDate | 202110 | 202111 | 202112 | 202201 | 202202 | 202203 | 202204 | 202205 | 202206 | 202207 | 202208 | 202209 | 202210 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aa | 2021-10-14 | 2021-12-22 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Ab | 2021-12-02 | 2022-10-05 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kiZFS2dX).

The above uses a standard test for date range overlap of "start1 <= end2 AND start2 <= end1", which assumes all dates are inclusive.